# how to two-way link between a python object and an ipywidget

Tags: events, traits, ipywidgets

Dear `ipywidgets` gurus,

I want to set up a link between the attribute of some python object and the value of some ipywidget:

```
import ipywidgets as ipyw

w = ipyw.IntSlider(42)

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, i=0):
        self.i = i  # not a traitlet, just an integer
foo = Foo(w.value)

two_way_link((w, 'value'), (foo, 'i'))  # mimics ipyw.link()

foo.i = 5  # will move the slider of w
w.value = 8  # update foo.i
```

I thought of `two_way_link` instantiating a wrapper traitlet around foo.i and then use `ipyw.link` with this wrapper and `w.value`. Maybe someone can suggest and alternative method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal python attributes (`Foo.i`, here) do not give any signals/events out of the box, so there is not any existing way to do this. A one way link from the traitlet to the attribute is possible by observing the traitlet, and having the handler set the attribute (`ipywidget.dlink` might already support this, not sure). Having something that goes the other way, you might have some luck with a `__setattr__` method on `Foo` ([https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**setattr**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)).

Comment: yes, in the end I had to resort to `Foo.__setattr__` to notify the ipywidget of changes in Foo instances. Thanks for the tip